# Remove specific partial string including special characters from string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Imagine I have a string like:

```
* This could be any text really - maybe even with strange characters --skip-ci
```

From this string using `sed` in my bash I want to remove the *possibly* occuring `--skip-ci` part.
I managed to come across a regexp using word boundary to remove the `skip-ci` part.

It looks like:
`\bskip-ci\b`

Unfortunately this isn't working in my bash and it will not remove the `--` as well (Using it like: `sed '\bskip-ci\b'`).

If you can give me a hint what to look for, that'd be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed s/'--skip-ci'/''/g test.txt
```

output:

```
2016-11-02 16:45:29 ☆  DESKTOP in ~
  ○ → more test.txt
* This could be any text really - maybe even with strange characters --skip-ci

2016-11-02 16:45:58 ☆  DESKTOP in ~
  ○ → sed s/'--skip-ci'/''/g test.txt
* This could be any text really - maybe even with strange characters
```

Comment: Working as expected, thank you. You may want to add the same output without saving it to a file. It looks the same without the `test.txt` in the end. Other than that, great! Thanks. Accepting your answer in 7 minutes ;)

Comment: @PhilippMeissner the `test.txt` is the file on which sed is working. Glad it helped

Comment: Why wouldn't you keep the whole thing in single quotes?

Comment: @123 to underline the fact that we replace it with a blank string, it's not mandatory